# Mapping labels from one file to another

Tags: bash, shell

I have two files

File A:

```
John
Janice
Carry
Ethan
```

File B:

```
2 Ronny
1 Michelle
2 John
2 Janice
10 Carry
1 Ethan
```

I want to get this first column(numbers) from file B to file A so that I can have file A of this sort

```
2 John
2 Janice
10 Carry
1 Ethan
```

How can I do it using bash?

Comment: `man 1 join` is your friend

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` one-liner will do the trick:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}($0 in a){print a[$0],$0}' file2 file1 
2 John
2 Janice
10 Carry
1 Ethan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Perl`:

```
open( A, "<", "A.txt" ) or die "Cannot open A.txt\n";  # open A.txt for reading
open( B, "<", "B.txt" ) or die "Cannot open B.txt\n";  # open B.txt for reading
chomp( my @A = <A> );                                  # get rid of newlines
while(my $bline = <B>){                             # iterate B.txt
    chomp( $bline );                                    # get rid of newline
    @ha = split /\s+/, $bline;                          # split to get 2nd field (name)
    if ( grep{ /$ha[1]/ } @A ) {                        # if 2nd field found in A array
        print $bline . "\n";            
    }       
}
close( A );                                            # close A file descriptor
close( B );                                            # close B file descriptor
```